# R-spatstat: How to relate 2 marks after using nnwhich

Tags: r, spatstat

I have 1 ppp with each point represents a farm. There are 2 marks attached to it.

1) Multitype marks: disease status (0=Not diseased, 1=Diseased) => DS1

2) Numeric Marks: Number of diseased animals => ND1

I don't want to be confused by those marks so I separated them into 2 ppp for each marks

```
sep_farm <- unstack.ppp(farm)
#Extract 'number of positive animals'from the sep_farm
ND2 <- sep_farm[["ND1"]]
#Extract 'disease status' from the sep_farm
DS2 <- sep_farm[["DS1"]]
```

I want to find the 1st-nearest diseased and non-diseased farm,
so I use;

```
n1 <- nnwhich(DS2, k=1, by=marks(DS2))
```

The problem is that I also want to know the number of diseased animals in each 1st-nearest diseased farm as well.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake data to test with:

```r
library(spatstat)
n <- 10
set.seed(42)
ds <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)
nd <- rpois(n, 100) * ds
farm <- runifpoint(n)
marks(farm) <- data.frame(DS1 = factor(ds), ND1 = nd)
marks(farm)
#>    DS1 ND1
#> 1    1  98
#> 2    1 115
#> 3    0   0
#> 4    1 120
#> 5    1  99
#> 6    1 113
#> 7    1 122
#> 8    0   0
#> 9    1 113
#> 10   1 109
```

Plot of fake data with number of diseased animals given below each
location

```r
plot(farm, which.marks = "DS1", cols = c("red", "blue"))
text(farm$x, farm$y, labels = nd, pos = 1, col = ifelse(ds==0, "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Existing code from question:

```r
sep_farm <- unstack.ppp(farm)
ND2 <- sep_farm[["ND1"]]
DS2 <- sep_farm[["DS1"]]
n1 <- nnwhich(DS2, k=1, by=marks(DS2))
```

Use indices to extract relevant marks

```r
ND_neigh <- marks(ND2)[n1[,2]]
```

Plot of result with number of diseased animals **at nearest infected
farm** given **above** each location (with own disease count below
still)

```r
plot(farm, which.marks = "DS1", cols = c("red", "blue"))
text(farm$x, farm$y, labels = nd, pos = 1)
text(farm$x, farm$y, labels = ND_neigh, pos = 3, col = "green")
```

[image]